# run-time error 1004 Application Defined or object-define error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have this macro that I wrote:

```
Dim lastColumn As Long
lastColumns = wkbWorkbook2.Worksheets(2).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'this is the highlighted part in debug

SourceRange.Copy
wkbWorkbook2.Worksheets(2).Cells(1, lastColumns + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,       Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
  :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Originally, the code above is part of a bigger code. But when I execute it,  it gives me the runtime error 1004.

But when I tried to execute it alone, it does work. So where could I be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `Columns.Count` is not referenced to `wkbWorkbook2.Worksheets(2)`. It's referenced to the *active workbooks/sheet*. Does your macro switch between different workbooks/sheets?